# Comparing group-by result with aggregated result

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I am trying to retrieve details about stores where their average product prices are higher than the average of all stores in the table.

So far, I have this code:

```
select StoreID, count(ProductID) from Products
where (select avg(Price) from Products group by StoreID) > (select avg(Price) from Products)
group by StoreID;
```

But this returns the following error:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

In terms of data, I would like to get this result:

```
StoreID  count(ProductID)
-------  ----------------
1        2
2        4
```

where the average prices of those stores are:

```
StoreID  avg(Price)
-------  ----------
1        6.5
2        7.5
```

and the average price of all stores is 4.6.

Can you help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to express:

```
select p.StoreID, count(*)
from Products
group by p.StoreId
having avg(Price) > (select avg(Price) from Products);
```

That is, you want a `having` clause and don't need to re-aggregate the data at the `StoreId` level.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the simplest answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using analytical function as following:

```
Select distinct storeid, store_avg from
(Select t.*,
       Avg(price) over () as all_avg,
       Avg(price) over (partition by storeid) as store_avg
From products)
Where store_avg > all_avg;
```

Cheers!!